# Nodejs using pulsar clinet by basic authentication

Tags: node.js, apache-pulsar

Can nodejs's `pulsar-client` use basic authentication?

I cannot find any example for use basic authentication.

https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/3.1.x/security-basic-auth/

It seems not support yet?